# Parsing GenBank to FASTA with yield in Python (x, y)

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics, fasta, genbank

For now I have tried to define and document my own function to do it, but I am encountering issues with testing the code and I have actually no idea if it is correct. I found some solutions with BioPython, re or other, but I really want to make this work with yield.

```
#generator for GenBank to FASTA
def parse_GB_to_FASTA (lines):
    #set Default label
    curr_label = None
    #set Default sequence
    curr_seq = ""
    for line in lines:
        #if the line starts with ACCESSION this should be saved as the beginning of the label
        if line.startswith('ACCESSION'):
            #if the label has already been changed
            if curr_label is not None:
                #output the label and sequence
                yield curr_label, curr_seq
                ''' if the label starts with ACCESSION, immediately replace the current label with
                the next ACCESSION number and continue with the next check'''
            #strip the first column and leave the number
            curr_label = '>' + line.strip()[12:]
        #check for the organism column
        elif line.startswith ('  ORGANISM'):
            #add the organism name to the label line
            curr_label = curr_label + " " + line.strip()[12:]
        #check if the region of the sequence starts
        elif line.startswith ('ORIGIN'):
            #until the end of the sequence is reached
            while line.startswith ('//') is False:
                #get a line without spaces and numbers
                curr_seq += line.upper().strip()[12:].translate(None, '1234567890 ')
    #if no more lines, then give the last label and sequence            
    yield curr_label, curr_seq
```

Comment: Examples of the input and expected output would help to test code with. I can't help but notice that here, your yield statement isn't part of the loop- it can't return each separate value of curr_label, because it only ever returns the last value (whatever was set after looping over everything). You may want to check your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I often work with very large GenBank files and found (years ago) that the BioPython parsers were too brittle to make it through 100's of thousands of records (at the time), without crashing on an unusual record.

I wrote a pure python(2) function to return the next whole record from an open file, reading in 1k chunks, and leaving the file pointer ready to get the next record.  I tied this in with a simple iterator that uses this function, and a GenBank Record class which has a fasta(self) method to get a fasta version.

YMMV, but the function that gets the next record is here as should be pluggable in any iterator scheme you want to use. As far as converting to fasta goes you can use logic similar to your ACCESSION and ORIGIN grabbing above, or you can get the text of sections (like ORIGIN) using:

```
sectionTitle='ORIGIN'    
searchRslt=re.search(r'^(%s.+?)^\S'%sectionTitle,
                     gbrText,re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL) 
sectionText=searchRslt.groups()[0]
```

Subsections like ORGANISM, require a left side pad of 5 spaces.

Here's my solution to the main issue:

```
def getNextRecordFromOpenFile(fHandle):
    """Look in file for the next GenBank record
    return text of the record
    """
    cSize =1024
    recFound = False
    recChunks = []
    try:
        fHandle.seek(-1,1)
    except IOError:
        pass
    sPos = fHandle.tell()

    gbr=None
    while True:
        cPos=fHandle.tell()
        c=fHandle.read(cSize)
        if c=='':
            return None
        if not recFound:

            locusPos=c.find('\nLOCUS')
            if sPos==0 and c.startswith('LOCUS'):
                locusPos=0
            elif locusPos == -1:
                continue
            if locusPos>0:
                locusPos+=1
            c=c[locusPos:]
            recFound=True
        else:
            locusPos=0

        if (len(recChunks)>0 and
            ((c.startswith('//\n') and recChunks[-1].endswith('\n'))
             or (c.startswith('\n') and recChunks[-1].endswith('\n//'))
             or (c.startswith('/\n') and recChunks[-1].endswith('\n/'))
             )):
            eorPos=0
        else:
            eorPos=c.find('\n//\n',locusPos)

        if eorPos == -1:
            recChunks.append(c)
        else:
            recChunks.append(c[:(eorPos+4)])
            gbrText=''.join(recChunks)
            fHandle.seek(cPos-locusPos+eorPos)
            return gbrText
```